# why adding group to my regex changes what it catches

Tags: regex

I have the line:

```
[asos-qa:2021:5]@0 Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] ]: 6, 23 |
```

I want to get the first word: `asos-qa`, so I tried this regex: `^\[\S*?(:|])` and it gets me: `[asos-qa:`.

So in order to get only the word without the other characters I tried to add a group (python syntax): `^\[(?P<app_id>\S*)?(:|])` but for some reason it returns `[asos-qa:2021:5]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Like this? `^\[([^:]+)` https://regex101.com/r/NllCw5/1

Comment: You have a typo, you escaped the `(`, `^\[(?P<app_id>\S*)?(:|])` is the fixed variant

Comment: but it does not include the `-qa` I want everything between the `[` and the first `:`

Comment: @EmaIl no it is  include '-qa' look at the link of him: https://regex101.com/r/NllCw5/1

Comment: @SL5net my python says differently :)

Comment: Please add a tag for the regex engine you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`^\[(?P<app_id>\S*)?(:|])` regex](https://regex101.com/r/tkRB3i/2) returns `[asos-qa:2021:5]` because `\S*` matches any zero or more non-whitespace chars *greedily* up to the *last* available `:`or `]` in the current chunk of non-whitespace chars, `?` you used is applied to the whole `(?P<app_id>\S*)` group pattern and is also greedy, i.e. the regex engine tries at least once to match the group pattern.

You need

```
^\[(?P<app_id>[^]\s:]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tkRB3i/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?P<app_id>[^]\s:]+)` - Group "app_id": any one or more chars other than `]`, whitespace and `:`. NOTE: `]` does not need to be escaped when it is the first char in the character class.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2sf2BA):

```py
import re
pattern = r"^\[(?P<app_id>[^]\s:]+)"
text = "[asos-qa:2021:5]@0 Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] ]: 6, 23 |"
m = re.search(pattern, text)
if m:
    print( m.group(1) )

# => asos-qa
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern uses a greedy `\S` which matches any non whitespace character.

You can make it non greedy using `\S*?` like   `^\[(?P<app_id>\S*?)(:|])` which will [have the value](https://regex101.com/r/6nYNoz/1) in capture group 1.

Or you can use a negated character class not matching `:` assuming the closing `]` will be there.

```
^\[(?P<app_id>[^:]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WZvnpw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ea1XDF)

Example code

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\[(?P<app_id>[^:]+)"
s = "[asos-qa:2021:5]@0 Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] ]: 6, 23 |"
match = re.match(pattern, s)
if match:
    print(match.group("app_id"))
```

Output

```
asos-qa
```

---

Or matching only words characters with an optional hyphen in between:

```
^\[(?P<app_id>\w+(?:-\w+)*)[^]\[]*]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yrXokx/1)